# Replace string with image

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to replace certain strings with an image.  All strings are enclosed in {} and when the code sees the [} what's inside will be read and what it equals will become the specific image. I haven't the foggiest how to implement this and was hoping someone could give me an example.

Here's my example to better explain:

```
{1} is replaced with an image
```

So, when the code sees the {} it will activate. Now so it does not interfere with other parts of the code it is limited to 1 character and only certain characters. This is for magic card casting costs to be more specific. So it would be limited too.....

B,U,R,G,W,X,T, 1-99 for example

===============================

So.....something like this?

```
$image_string = '{R}{R}{R}{3}

$Mana_symbol ='BURGWXT1-99';

$output = preg_replace_all('/\{([' . $Mana_symbol. '])\}/', '<img src="\1.png"/>', $string);

switch ($output)
{
    case ('B'):
        $mana = '<img src = "black_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('U'):
        $mana = '<img src = "blue_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('G'):
        $mana = '<img src = "green_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('R'):
        $mana = '<img src = "red_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('W'):
        $mana = '<img src = "white_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('1'):
        $mana = '<img src = "1_colorless_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('2'):
        $mana = '<img src = "2_colorless_mana.png"/>';
        break;
    case ('3'):
        $mana = '<img src = "3_colorless_mana.png"/>';
        break;

        ....etc....
```

Should't I use preg_replace_all since there will be some with multiple instances of this? Like in the case  example as the $image_string above it will replace all occurances in the string that match?

Comment: Are the strings read in from a db or file or user input or are they embedded within existing HTML or PHP?  As far as what replaces the values within the {} do you have some sort of map or lookup, or is this something stored in a database table?

Comment: The information is being pulled from an XML file and then the variables are assigned and posts are automatically created from the info pulled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using regular expressions (see http://www.php.net/pcre):

Say your images are called `x.png` for a tag `{x}`:

```
<?php

$string = '{1} is replaced with an image';

// Use a regular expression
// The codes below will be placed into a character class
$validCodes = 'BURGWXT0-9';

// This array contains the image transforms
$images = array(
    'B' => 'black_mana.png',
    'U' => 'blue_mana.png',
    // ...
);

// Use preg replace to insert the images
$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{([' . $validCodes . ']+)\}/',
    function($m) use ($images) {
        if (isset($images[$m[1]])) {
            return '<img src="' . $images[$m[1]] . '"/>';
        }
        return '';
    },
    $string
);

echo $string;

?>
```

Please ask if you need further clarification.

**Edit**

I've added a mechanism for you to add your own transforms by populating an array.

`preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` will both replace all occurances they find in the string.

Note that the anonymous function I've used is only available in PHP 5.3.0+ (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

**Edit 2**

I've just realised that the character class for the regex wouldn't capture all your characters, and that you'd need the + after the character class to capture some of your codes.

Comment: I've added my response to your answer in the original post above as it was too big to put in comments :)

Comment: Hi Pete this deletes the entire description area when inserting product data. Would you mind taking a look at this code? http://codepad.org/okkOKaIj  ....And I'm also running PHP 5.3.10 and the anonymous function works fine.

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `preg_replace_callback` needs to be `$ability` in your code - you're passing it an empty string.

Comment: ah Doh! I fixed that, but the code doesn't return images it eithe returns nothing or it returns (,)....example {T} returns (,) and {2} returns nothing.....

Comment: I've just run the code from your previous listing, with the `$ability` change, and it works as expected for me - try `var_dump($ability);` after the replace to check the contents of the string.

Comment: Found it. I forgot to remove wp_strip_all_tags for $ability in array for wp_insert_post. Thanks for the help Pete :)

Comment: So far they look fine even in instances where its {W}{W},{T}: blah blah blah.

Answer (score 1):

Youu could use a regular expression to parse all the {}'s out then str_replace them later

`preg_match_all('/{(1|2|3|99|a)}/', "{1} is replaced with an image{a} {99}", $match)`